# Given a set of generators of a group $G$, is there a method to find a presentation for $G$ using those generators?

Tags: algorithms, exact-sequence, gap, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose I have a group $G$, which I know is finitely presentable and infinite. (In particular, I have a presentation for it, though not the one I want).

Suppose I have a small list of generators $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ for $G$.

Is there an algorithm to find a presentation for $G$ using the given generators?

More specifically, I have an exact sequence of finitely presented groups $$1\rightarrow F_2\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1$$
Here $F_2$ is the free group on 2 generators, and I have presentations for both $G$ and $H$. I'd like to find a presentation of $G$ where the generators have the form $\{x,y,g_1,\ldots,g_k\}$, where $x,y$ are the two free generators of $F_2$.

It looks like GAP would allow me to do this for finite groups $G$, though the same function does not appear to work for infinite groups.

Comment: What else do you know about $G$? To run an algorithm, you need some input.

Comment: I have a presentation. It's not that terrible either - 4 generators, 8 relations.

Comment: Then the answer is yes, it's just the standard way of changing the presentation when we change the generators, it can be found on standard textbooks such as Lyndon-Schupp.

Comment: In general, if you have a presentation on a (finite) set of generators $X$ and you have another set of generators $Y$, and you can express the generators of $X$ in terms of those of $Y$, and those of $Y$ in terms of $X$, then it is routine to compute a presentation on $Y$. I think you can do this in GAP using Tietze transformations. You should ask for help on the GAP forum.

Comment: Start with your known presentation of $G$. Express each of $x$ and $y$ as terms built from those generators.  Adjoin to your known presentation the two generators $x$ and $y$, and adjoin to the known relations the two equations that express $x$ and $y$ in terms of the original generators.